# How to set the workspace to a featureclass from an unknown file gdb?

Tags: arcobjects

When a user loads an mxd, I am getting the IWorkspace object from the featurelayer's dataset:

```
IFeatureClass featClass = (IFeatureClass)featLayer.FeatureClass;
IDataset dataSet = (IDataset)featClass.FeatureDataset;
IWorkspace workSpace = (IWorkspace)dataSet.Workspace;
```

But this obviously does not work if the user has a layer from a file geodatabase (dataset is null).

I can check to see if it's a gdb layer but nothing in the featurelayer or its featureclass tells me the source of the gdb.

How do I go about setting the workspace object to a featurelayer that comes from a gdb?

Comment: IS THIS RESOLVED?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line

```
IDataset dataSet = (IDataset)featClass.FeatureDataset;
```

to

```
IDataset dataset = (IDataset)featClass;
```

Comment: Simple as that. QI the featclass to the dataset gives me the fgdb path in its workspace property. Thank you very much.